# Feel for you or feel about you?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

So there is this girl I really like. Should I tell her that I feel **about** her or that I feel **for** her?

What is the difference between using **for** or **about** in this context or when would you use **for** and when would you use **about**?

Comment: In your exact context ***about*** is much more likely. Usually when you talk about feeling ***for*** someone, the implication is you feel ***sorry*** for them. Or at least, that you ***empathise*** with them -  you're claiming to have the *same* feelings, so you're feeling ***for them/on their behalf.***

Comment: There's a very common expression "I have feelings for _____" to be used when someone has romantic feelings for a person so it's not that out of the ordinary but in OP's context, he is asking whether he should tell her how he feels *about* her.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I guess that is the expression that might have gotten me confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To *feel for* someone means to have compassion for them, see definition 2.5 in [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feel). The example sentence is

> Poor woman, I feel for her.

*feel about* is used to describe the emotions or opinions you have regarding someone or something. This is what you would use when talking about why you like or dislike someone.

Answer (score 1):

feel about: have an opinion about that person

feel for: have sympathy for that person